# How to check the innerHTML area of a jQuery variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, html-parsing

Let's say that I have the following stored in a jQuery variable.

```
<i class="a b c"></i><span class="itemLabel d"><span><i class="e f g"></i>something</span></span>
```

Here the text I want to examine is "something." I want to make sure that that text is "something" and not something else. How can that be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var stuff = jQuery('<i class="a b c"></i><span class="itemLabel d"><span><i class="e f g"></i>something</span></span>');

alert(stuff.text() === "something");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/We2nf/

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like,

```
var $something = $jqVariable.find(':contains("something")');

if($something.length === 0 ){//Its something else}
else{//do something with the "$something"}
```

I used [`contains`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) selector and here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EUrWB/2/).

**Update:**

Its also possible that if multiple elements contains the same text (eg:something)
in the `$jqVariable`, then the
length of `$something` will be more than `1`. At that time you would do,

```
$something.each(function(){
    // do something with the each "something" :)
});
```